# button in webView execute Objective C method

Tags: javascript, ios, webview

There is a button in a UIWebview, I need to implement the function that jumping another UIView when tap the this button, in other word, execute the following function: [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"homePage" sender:self];

I tried to use shouldStartLoadWithRequest function, but it doesn't work. If you can show me a small demo, you'll be very appreciated! Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<!--index.html-->
<p>Hello World!</p>
<p><h1>Link</h1>
<a href='appintern://home'>Home</a>
</p>
<p>
<h1>Button</h1>
<form method="post" action="home">
    <button type="submit">Continue</button>
</form>
</p>
```

Load html into web view:

```
// html path
NSString *htmlPath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"index" ofType:@"html"];
// html data
NSData *htmlData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:htmlPath];
// load html in webview
[self.mainWebView loadData:htmlData MIMEType:@"text/html" textEncodingName:@"utf-8" baseURL:nil];
```

In Delegate method:

```
- (BOOL)webView:(UIWebView *)webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType {

    if (navigationType == UIWebViewNavigationTypeFormSubmitted) {
        NSString *destination = [request.URL lastPathComponent];
        if ([destination isEqualToString:@"home"]) {
            NSLog(@"go to home");
            //[self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"homePage" sender:self];
            return NO;
        }
    }
    else if (navigationType == UIWebViewNavigationTypeLinkClicked) {
        // todo
    }

    return YES;
}
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Nice! I forgot set up delegate of webview. The problem is fixed.  Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to use URL schemes to communicate from your html web page to Obj C:  http://www.macstories.net/tutorials/guide-url-scheme-ios-drafts/

Have your submit button open the URL scheme that you will drive the results you want.  TIP:  URL Schemes are really API-like calls.  You want to make sure that they contain enough Idenfying information so that adding more schemes can be done intelligently.

Comment: Thanks for your replying. It's also helpful.